# How to find out number of methods in dex which hits - Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android

Recently, I was hit by

[Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

I came across 2 code which able to measure number of methods in a dex

- https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/6004640
- https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/6002797

Both methods require me to have the generated dex file, in order to perform measurement.

But, what I can do, if I wasn't able to even generate the dex file, due to large number of methods?

Comment: Perhaps this will help : http://www.betaful.com/2013/10/android-too-many-methods-dex-fails/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Linux environment

### Grab all of the jar files

```
mkdir jars
cp **/*.jar jars
```

### Iterate through them, displaying the method size

```
for file in jars/*.jar; do
  echo $file; ~/android-sdk/build-tools/17.0.0/dx --dex --output=temp.dex $file 2> /dev/null
  cat temp.dex| head -c 92 | tail -c 4 | hexdump -e '1/4 "%d\n"'
done
```

Credit to http://betaful.com/post/82668814182/android-too-many-methods-dex-fails