# android studio , gradle dex failed

Tags: android

I'm trying to build my android project with gradle but i keep getting this failed message that i can really understand, when I'm not using gradle everything is working smooth , what am i doing wrong?

```
:Wrap:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Wrap:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/nirkeren/Downloads/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20131030/sdk/build-tools/19.0.3/dx --dex --output /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/dex/debug /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/classes/debug /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/dependency-cache/debug /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/activation-371528ff37ca00b95f4aaa30e7ada077808b4066.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/additionnal-cbe08f392e3489e0bbc657eaa6e1b2c578c8c63a.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/aws-android-sdk-1.7.1.1-1063abd88670acb74ffa18e83bed84e1185d156e.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-00b425e022f3e5825d218bf8230a3518488661ad.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-1536774be9f5f226247f33ff39444641cbae5f17.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-319df0e8b970ed8444fa4ad2a35d7b04d8635cf7.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-3a528328da2ecd26bde330cd6e96a93681e37443.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-88cca99f18ad79854e456d941016a7ba2d89778b.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-b427cc929fd1399dd3b95eb4f41a07465f532aaf.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/classes-b7ec143e0b6817ac519f67d77d80b2574ceaac79.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/crashlytics-a9be38ef9142a13510daa326a3e74e79ec26fe81.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-api-client-1.15.0-rc-e5d0bfc007123ab793084359d1ef33a23786b1cc.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-api-client-android-1.15.0-rc-91914619bb0c2177957554eee1e41988a12b4111.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev76-1.15.0-rc-9fc7b1dbf3fa9980bb1471a02e67a59ea7b0e7e4.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-http-client-1.15.0-rc-c609d62345e69e29cff2e79286c99b2287dc1935.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-http-client-android-1.15.0-rc-219670662f5d9c8793501be852143a90ad8bcfc9.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-http-client-gson-1.15.0-rc-2bc2a42d04283a6e31550ba6fb50a545a295e1d7.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-oauth-client-1.15.0-rc-3de236b42e6497978cf52f309ed16c0dd47a7e4a.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/google-play-services-d4c8a0bc9c8586e19cc569471ba95580ff827f24.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/gson-2.1-5dd6330840355abbdb328e202fb7a1b601c11625.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/httpclient-4.0.1-6d6f0a4ccfe934c72fcd285cd0bd138903838075.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/httpcore-4.0.1-651bf829da8a88ebcba183426bdc2a5816a8a8f8.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/jsr305-1.3.9-17a8eef10544db30421f617a1a74033dc44e0b5a.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/libGoogleAnalyticsServices-20f33d61149fc3986571664bce4d5a71b7375d77.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/library-2.4.0-cf8b4e3adb01d32f9c0a19763d14e0d5a6fc58cb.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/mail-368bf8fea3a96aaffa7fe8eb7a39f1c975584527.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/opencsv-2.3-60231b26d86a13ba9a7e4d523848b462313d909f.jar /Users/nirkeren/projects/ONDiGO_1_1_0/Wrap/build/pre-dexed/debug/support-v4-19.1.0-00876ab3fdbf97f4dfe545f08a39e533888e15b1.jar
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Answer (score 0):

Your project is too large. You have too many methods. There can only be 65536 methods per application. Try to reduce unnecessary methods or update your Android Support Library to 21 revision