# Android Dex - errors after add jackson libraries

Tags: android, dex

Recently i have added below mentioned jackson jar to libs folder in my project.

```
1.jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
2.jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
3.jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
```

Suddenly getting below errors when i run my project.

```
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] Unable to execute DX
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:501)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:276)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:490)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:161)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:294)
Error:Android Dex: [MyProjectName] at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:121)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now days android developer site provide guideline to resolve this problem :

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Updated :

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html

Answer (score 1):

It looks similar to this one: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536).

The reason is that the maximum methods in a dex file is 65536.

**[Edit]**

I'm not sure if this is a good idea. I just read an article about dynamically load jar file on runtime. In this way, you have to remove maybe one or two jar first and make sure your application can run. Then, load another jar on runtime.

Here's tutorial: blog.csdn.net/bboyfeiyu/article/details/11710497

Comment: Yes you right but can you please explain me what i have to do for this error solution ?

Comment: I think the right way is to remove unnecessary dependencies :)

But if there's nothing I can remove, I'll try to load those jar files dynamically (because those jar files are really important, isn't it?)

Comment: Try using proguard. It should strip out any unused methods and bring your overall method count down.