# Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, apk, dex

My app has crossed maximum limit of methods i.e. 65536 methods.

In my application I have used 16 jar files ans 4 library projects.

What I already done(which is not working):

1. Common out all jars from my application and library projects.
2. Kept a common android support library.
3. Removed android dependencies.
4. Used jars externally.

I don't want to create multiple apk for my application, is there any other idea achieving this.

Comment: use proguard to remove unused methods/classes ...

Comment: @Selvin thanks ...let me try

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: @RooMan yes it is ... but here I want single apk for my app :-)

Comment: Try renaming all your android library projects to the same package name in the AndroidManifest.xml. This will decrease the method count by shrinking the size of R.java.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some time - in this podcast:

http://androidbackstage.blogspot.de/2014/08/android-developers-backstage-episode-11.html

it is mentioned that there will be an official solution to this in the future (multi-dex)

there are some workarounds around today - but AFAIK all of them are kind of hacky