# Error of "Unable to execute dex: field ID not in" in Eclipse

Tags: android, dalvik

I have done several solutions which don't solve this problem for some hours (I am using Eclipse):

> [dex loader unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928392/dex-loader-unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)
>
> Accepted answer in
>   [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)
>
> and some others

I believe google-play-services.jar is the cause.

How to solve this kind of error?

Comment: I faced the same issue many times and there are many possibilities. Something wrong in your layout file, a conflict of `.jar` file that you used,etc.

Comment: I believe this more to amount of my methods that exceed 65k since I also have some other jars with total of 9MB + google-play-services

Comment: Your question subject implies you're running out of field ids, not method ids.

Comment: But what I could find out there it's caused by exceed amount of method

Comment: For my project also  I am getting same error : Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: field ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 In my project method count is 55K.