# Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

In my ADT eclipse am getting this following error while am try to my android app

```
[2015-08-28 17:47:05 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2015-08-28 17:47:05 - FITBLINK] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I have added

```
multiDexEnabled=true
manifestmerger.enabled=true
dex.force.jumbo=true
target=android-21
```

in my project.properties file, but no use.

I have unchecked the jar file in order&export and i checked only private and dependencies library. if any one know, please tell me step by step to resole this issue, in ADT Eclipse

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Jump to Android Studio`

Comment: Sorry my project is almost done. if am switching to android studio it will take lot of time to reset all library file. around 12 library am using in my app. So will u pls tell me how to fix it ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse ADT based Android build system does not support creating multidex APKs. So your only chance is to reduce the number of methods to less than 65536 so that they fit into a single dex file.

Comment: HOw to do it and where i can do in ?? in project.properties

Comment: There is nothing you can configure in the build system to solve this. You have to refactor your code to use fewer Java methods and / or libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Someone else has asked this question before. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536).

I'm having that exact problem in my own project. I'm afraid I'll have to do some serious refactoring...

Comment: This is for android studio. Ofcourse am usnig google_play_service lib. But how i can reduce the no.of methods????

Comment: I am using Eclipse ADT, just like you are, and I'm having this problem, too. In my case, I'm writing an app for an already existing huge project with tons of dependencies. And I'll have to come up with a way to make the Android structure not include any dependencies it does not explicitly use. All in all - I suggest you do the same for your project. Unfortunately, there isn't an easy solution to this problem if you're still stuck with Eclipse.

Comment: The same problem am facing dude.. am also doing existing project with huge libraries but i need to overcome from this issue becoz my app is almost done. if i am switching to studio, it will take too much time .. so if you know the way pls share with me

Comment: Just make sure that you only use those libraries that the app actually needs. Easier said than done, obviously... I'm using Maven and I've just excluded a lot of jars that were listed in my Maven dependencies and never used. Now my application runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced like this problem in eclipse IDE when I used the lasted version of google-paly-service.But when I replaced with older goolge-play-service, it fixed my problem. I also referenced this Stack Over Flow page. [dex loader unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25928392/dex-loader-unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536). I hope it will help you.