# Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]:

Tags: android, eclipse, dex

I know this question hase been asked many times but I have some weird issue where it was running fine in ADT v22 but when I update my eclipse to v23 I got this error

Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

any help is appreciated

**Update**: Issue got fixed when I used Android Studio with multidex option.

Answer (score 2):

You have reached [the 64K DEX method reference limit](http://www.hellsoft.se/android/androids-64k-method-limit/). Most likely, you will need to remove some libraries to reduce the size of your app.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Your project is too large. You have too many methods. There can only be 65536 methods per application. see here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7147#c6

Ref : [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Answer (score 0):

Real simple method I found here to fix this problem.

I was using many external libraries in my application. With this came huge number of unused methods. I could not find a way to enable multi-dex on eclipse either. So I went ahead and analyzed unused classes from external libraries which I was using.

Opened this jar files using 7zip, and deleted unnecessary classes. Done! :)