# DexIndexOverflowException issue after updating to latest appcompat and support library

Tags: android, gradle, android-5.0-lollipop, android-support-library, build.gradle

I'm using the below settings through `gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 21
ANDROID_BUILD_MIN_SDK_VERSION=14
ANDROID_BUILD_TARGET_SDK_VERSION=21
ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=21.0.2
ANDROID_BUILD_SDK_VERSION=21
```

I also have the following settings in my gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

I always get the error `UNEXPECTED TOP LEVEL EXCEPTION`.
But when I make the `21.0.0` to `20.0.0` it works fine...but i'm not able to access any of the Android API 21 options. Is there something i'm doing wrong here? How do I get it to compile without this exception? I do not have the support jars anywhere else outside of other grade projects (facebook etc.).

Here is the full stack trace:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: Did you dowenload all libraries and tools from SDK Manager?

Comment: Yep, I'm simply updating my app from API 19 to 21. All libraries from previous version and all the new libraries for 21.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/15209831

Answer (score 148, accepted):

This message sounds like your project is too large.

You have too many methods. There can only be **65536 methods for dex**.

Since the gradle plugin 0.14.0 and the Build Tools 21.1.0 you can use the [**multidex support**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Just add these lines in the `build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Also in your `Manifest` add the `MultiDexApplication` class from the multidex support library to the application element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"> 
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you are using a own `Application` class, change the parent class from `Application` to `MultiDexApplication`.

Comment: `multi-dex` was the reason for that.

Comment: Add multiDexEnabled true to the defaultConfig of your build.gradle file

Comment: I don't use build gradle file to build my app. Anyway to overcome this issue.?

Comment: interestingly only adding gradle config worked for me. Was the manifest config optional ?

Comment: I had to use the AndroidManifest.xml change in @georgehardcore's answer to get this to work.

Comment: @KimberlyW you may have just forgotten the forward slash to close the meta data element. Called a self-closing tag. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: i had to change the tag in the android manifest file to `<meta-data android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:value="true"/>` to get it to work for me. I'm using a multi-module project....if i didnt i'd get this error: `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED `

Comment: Thanks, it was very important and help me a lot.

Comment: You dont have to do anything to your Manifest.  Gradle is enough.

Answer (score 45):

1) add dependency to application build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
```

2) If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Or if you do override the Application class but it's not possible to change the base class, then you can instead override the attachBaseContext() method and call MultiDex.install(this) to enable multidex:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

3) Add multidex support to defaultConfig at build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        ...
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
...
```

Comment: Perfect! @georgehardcore

Comment: @georgehardcore: i used second point, in my android eclipse project.but still it is showing same error.

Comment: try to split google-play-services library if you are uisng it. For example, if you use analytics and gcm just plug them as separate modules with base module like: 

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'

Comment: @georgehardcore not sure if step #2 would be needed, 'cos it didn't help me on my application. So I skip it and the rest of the steps worked great!

Comment: For me it worked but without changing Application class to MultiDexApplication in the manifest nor MyApplication class

Answer (score 3):

### Before messing around with MultiDex

It either solution is too big (use MultiDex) or you compile and include in your project some not needed stuff. I got this issue on my tiny project. Here is what I did to fix it:

I removed this from `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

And I manually removed my build folder from application root. Problem fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Follow [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) guide to workaround 65K limit.

I solved this issue in gradle by setting `multiDexEnabled true` and extending my application with `class MyApp extends MultiDexApplication`

Answer (score 0):

I simply commented out the compile `filetree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`
in the `build.gradle` file (as suggested above) and rebuilt the project. Compiled without any errors. I did not need to move any folders.

Comment: Disregard my comment - subsequent rebuilds generated the same original error even when I manually deleted the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that minification is enabled in `app/build.cradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
```

If this does not solve the issue, enable [multidex build](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when i had compiled the entire package of Google Play Services APIs into my app. I solved the issue by using selective API.

For example, to include only the Google Fit and Android Wear APIs, replace the following line in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:11.0.2'
```

Issue is explained in following [link](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).