# Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 error in android studio using recycler view

Tags: android-studio, android-multidex

There are many solution for this error.

Some said increasing the heap memory of android studio will solve this.

Some, asking to use multi dex library.  [Multidex library setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

In my case, this issue occurs only at the time of adding recycler view as dependency in my project. Because my existing code project added to recycler-view might led to have over 65k line of code of my entire project. This is clear to me.

Now the only question I have got is, I don't use gradle build system in my project. Does any one have the complete steps to use Multidex library for Android studio build?  (Not gradle build)

My project structure:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/issue-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-library/26515860?noredirect=1#comment54391883_26515860

Comment: You can only have 65536 methods for dex. You have to use the multidex setup. Increasing the heap memory you will not resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't use build.gradle file. How can I enable this "multiDexEnabled true"?
and where in android studio?

Comment: Do you use Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Check inside your module folder. You should have the build.gradle file.

Comment: No ..   I don't have it. I have updated the question with screenshot of my project structure. You can check it..

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti   I am glad that I am one of your 2270 followers and you are trying to solve my issue.  :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93159/discussion-between-chakravarthi-and-gabriele-mariotti).