# How can i resolve multidex error in eclipse

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which app I am using too many libraries. Most recently I added mixpanel lib to my project. After that the build was successful. But when I try to run the app I am getting an error:

> [2015-11-06 15:04:54 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>   [2015-11-06 15:04:54 -] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

I have read so many articles. But I have not implemented in eclipse. Even if I add multidex jar to my app and extend my application class to mulidexapplication, I get the same error. Please any one help me.

Comment: A bit unrelated, but you should really consider switching to Android Studio.   Google is dropping support for the ADT plugin and has asked everyone to migrate to Android Studio.

Comment: You should switch to Android Studio at this time... ADT plugin is going out of support at the end of the year. Also it is very simple to resolve your case with a gradle script. Check for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/issue-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-library/26515860#26515860

Answer (score 3):

Working with too many libraries always cause this problem.

make sure you are not importing same library twice.

**For Example**,

You are using library let's say XYZ which imports **AppCompat** library. now you are importing this library to your main project which is also importing **AppCompat** library.

Now this **AppCompat** library has been imported twice in your project. so this may gives you error of `multiDex`.

so you can remove **AppCompact** From your main project.

then clean and run. will work fine.

hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You should move your code to Android Studio and when your gradle file is build successfully then enter this line in your gradle file

```
defaultConfig {

        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

since you project has more than 64K methods you it gives you the error.

Add the following statement your project `build.gradle` file will solve the issue it gives the error but it will execute no problem

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Please go through the [link](http://frogermcs.github.io/MultiDex-solution-for-64k-limit-in-Dalvik)