# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La;

Tags: android

I am using wikitudesdk  library in my android project but at runtime i am getting error "Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La" how to resolvet it.

Comment: see here http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @Tauqir , actually I am using eclipse . so how to manage gradle inside eclipse .I have also used android-support-multidex.jar . but I am getting same error as previous(Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La;) at rum time. at compile time there is no issue.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27911008/5202007 or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580075/how-can-i-resolve-multidex-error-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the same class name is found twice in the input, e.g. in a library and in the main program.

In your case the class name is just `a`, so proguard seems also to be in the mix.

For better help you need to provide more details.

Comment: actually I am using eclipse . so how to manage gradle inside eclipse .I have also used android-support-multidex.jar . but I am getting same error as previous(Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define La;) at rum time. at compile time there is no issue.