# Multidex issue in Eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making an application in Eclipse android but now getting me error multidex issue. I found many time but not get any exact solution to how can i resolved multidex issue in eclipse application. i aslo add multidex.jar and add multidex in application class but still getting error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android multidex support library using eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530654/android-multidex-support-library-using-eclipse)

Comment: migrate to Android Studio. :) Eclipse now is not supported

Comment: not possible to migrate in studio because code is so lengthy.

Comment: check my answer on this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33580982/5148289)