# Android Studio Gradle doesn't build my app when using Comparator class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, comparator

This compiles and builds fine:

```
Collections.sort(array, null);
```

This one doesn't:

```
Collections.sort(array, new Comparator<ChatText>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(ChatText o1, ChatText o2) {
            return (int) (o1.timestamp - o2.timestamp);
        }
    });
```

That's what I get:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42310Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers132Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta113Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics252Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore235Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk470Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric136Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 10.116 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Tried cleaning the project few times, didn't help. A solution without the usage of `Comparator` class would help too.

Comment: Possible explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing to do with Comparator class. You have reached your dexing limit. This means you have reached the limit for *references that can be invoked by the code within a single Dalvik Executable* ([Googles explanation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)). The solution is very easy. [Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/1642079) to see how to enable multidexing.