# Firebase client-android DexIndexOverflowException method ID not in 65536

Tags: android, firebase

I'm getting this exception when I'm trying to use Firebase client-android.

I saw several questions about it in sof (but not for firebase client-android) and the only solution was to set my application to multidex application.

Since it's not the recommended solution, can anyone suggest better solution?

Thank's

Comment: If you're having a dex overflow, you'll need to either reduce the code is included or multi-dex. Unless you have something that is unique about your case, I'll vote as a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I've already saw this kind of solution. I've read that Android dosen't recommend using it. I've tried it but I got OutOfMemoryException. It dosen't make sense to me that this is the only way to use Firebase Android SDK for user sign up/login.