# Kotlin gradle.build ZipException because of duplicates

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin

I add Kotlin to the gradle.build with dependency (Kotlin version 1.0.4):

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
```

As I found out it has a conflict with my other dependency:

```
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
```

After I run the build it crashes with the ZipException:

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable.class
```

**What I already tried:**

I tried this solution: 
[Kotlin,Java,multidex,Dagger 2,Butterknife and Realm: transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug: duplicate entry: org/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660420/kotlin-java-multidex-dagger-2-butterknife-and-realm-transformclasseswithjarmerg/39660615#39660615) 
But it ended up, that not only *Nullable.class* and *NotNull.class* were duplicates, but also classes from *org/intellij/lang/annotations/*.

After I added five classes it still crashed. Is there a better way to get rid of this problem, by not adding every class manually that causes this exception?

**UPDATE (02.02.16)**

As I worked a bit on the problem, I found out that for my project the relevant annotation classes are `NonNls.class` and `Contract.class` that are missing, if I remove `org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0`. They are not in kotlin-runtime, but in the Jetbrains annotation dependency. How can I add it without adding the Jetbrains annotation dependency again?

Comment: `kotlin-runtime` only bundles 4 annotations: `Nullable`, `NotNull`, `Mutable` and `ReadOnly`. So if you have other annotations clashing, they might come from another dependency.

Comment: Thank for your answer @Ilya. The solution I tried, worked with `NotNull` and `Nullable`. After that `Flow.class` was a duplicate. As I added `Flow.class` to the list for overriding the annotations.jar, another class was the problem. I think the problem is still with `annotations-java5`.

Comment: The simple way would be remove `compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'` as android-support library provides its own annotations, so try to use them intead of that got from IntelliJ.

Comment: how did you solve please tell. i am also stuck with this problem

Answer (score 1):

Try to use instead of:

```
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
```

this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'
```

Android support libraries by default provides like Kotlin a few most used annotations, so if you use basiscs like `@NonNull`, `@Nullable` and `@Null` annotations  you, remove above dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) Necessary for me is the NonNls annotation. As I see, it is not included in `'com.android.support:support-annotations:+'`.
The project is too big to refactor all the NonNls annotation usages.

Comment: remove both dependencies and change import to 'javax.annotation.NonNull'