# DexIndexOverflowException (MultiDex enabled) after switching to a Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-multidex

This was working fine on a Windows machine but I am trying to work on a Mac now and I'm getting `DexIndexOverflowException`. I have `multiDexEnabled true` in my build.gradle. I have extended the `MultiDexApplication` class and that class is in my `AndroidManifest` file.

`compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` is in my dependencies

I still get `DexIndexOverflowException`. I added the following to my `MultiDexApplication` class and it still didn't work:

```
@Override
public void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    MultiDex.install(base);
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
}
```

Comment: Did you add Application class path to AndroidManifest?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26515860/7001152

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. What worked for me was to selectively compile Google Play service APIs into my app. For example, in my case I was using Google Maps API, I had this in my gradle before:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'`

I had to change to these lines:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'`

so that not the whole Play Services API are compiled into my app.

Comment: It was actually a silly mistake. I had multidex enabled for the 'release' build type but I had the 'debug' build variant selected.