# trying to add google map , this error is comming

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn9D7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4oij.png)Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Comment: Please share a relevant snippet of your code, which causes the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception

Comment: ya , will share

Comment: main activity :

Comment: post your build.gradle file and manifest file

Comment: I will send it.

Answer (score 0):

Add multidex support, please refer [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l)

Some of your libraries adding same packages into the build path.

Answer (score 0):

adding multiDexEnabled true to your app build.gradle file.

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: You just copy and paste the answer [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception/32811133#32811133) posted by @JuliusScript and not even give the reference or credit to JuliusScript.