# error while building the apk in android

Tags: android

This is the my build.gradle and when I build the apk by clicking on the build apk this error shown.I have seen the some of the queries before but not able to figure out the problem solution

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ranjeet.location"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
}
```

Comment: Whats the error? Paste error log and also tell the android studio version you are using.

Comment: i have edited and paste it above

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DexIndexOverflowException issue after updating to latest appcompat and support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many methods. There can only be 65536 methods for dex.

So, enable multidex as following:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {
        ...

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

And paste this code as well,

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have too many methods. There can only be 65536 methods for dex.

So, enable multidex as following:

```
 android {    
    defaultConfig {
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }  
}



dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

The underlying problem is imposed by the current set of Dalvik instructions. Specifically, any of the invoke-* methods. These expect a 16-bit argument, representing the target method's reference index. Being limited to 16-bits, valid values are between 0 and 65536. This means, that if you end up calling more than 65,536 defined methods, you are going to exceed this limit.

Solutions：
  MultiDex allows you to use multiple DEX files contained within one APK. With a few steps, your classes will split automatically into several DEX files (classes.dex, classes2.dex, classes3.dex, etc) in case you reach the method index limit.

Get more infomation : https://www.contentful.com/blog/2014/10/30/android-and-the-dex-64k-methods-limit/

Answer (score 0):

If your **minSdkVersion** is set to **21 or higher**, all you need to do is set multiDexEnabled to true in your app-level `build.gradle` file, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 21 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}
```

However, if your **minSdkVersion** is set to **20 or lower**, then you must use the multidex support library as follows:

Modify the app-level `build.gradle` file to enable multidex and add the multidex library as a dependency, as shown here:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 15 
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Create an Application class like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Add this application class in Manifest.

You can also check this link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: You do not need to override attachBaseContext if your application extends MultiDexApplication