# Dex overflow exception .. using play services android

Tags: android, apk, dex

I know there is certain limit of functions for app.

I'm using play services and using resources from it like color resources etc

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2

what specific api should I compile with like 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-**services- ??????** :11.0.2'

Comment: You need to enable multiDex for your project, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26515860/6504367

Answer (score 1):

Do not use whole play services compile statement directly. You should include individual modules of play service that your app is using. For example if your app is using location services you should inly include

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4

or if you are using Google Analytics you should only include

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4

you can find individual module compile gradle statements here

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: I'm using resources from play services like @colors,symbols and I'm not finding in which module they are :(

Comment: what resources exactly? are you sure they belong to play services only?

Comment: Yes when I remove play services alot of resources errors occured ..like @color/ not found

Comment: Thats probably because your project is failing to build in first place and R.java is not created