# React Native Android App with 64k+ methods

Tags: react-native

I have problem with running RN Android app using react-native run-android

It throws exception at the build stage and can't figure out the issue.

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-firebase:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I've tried various solutions on the web and it was all in vein.
Tried solutions were enabling multiDex and increase the javaMaxHeapSize in dexOptions.

This error can be seen as a library or component dependent, but it happens for any kind of apps which exceeds 64k limits.

One more thing:
It compiles without any problem in Android Studio

Comment: Have you tried [enabling jumbo mode](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/328) (first hit on Google)?

Answer (score 5):

With react 0.60 I was having this issue, and adding multiDexEnabled true to my defaultConfig (android/app/build.gradle) fixed it:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ...
}
```

Comment: this saved me. You perhaps need this line only. try. it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many methods by the look of it. This a common DEX issue. As mentioned here:

[DexIndexOverflowException issue after updating to latest appcompat and support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l)

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
android {

  defaultConfig {
    ...

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ...
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Then in your Android Manifest add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
      ...
      android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"> 
      ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Let me know if this helps! I have come across this issue before myself.