# when convert Java to Kotlin, com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-multidex

After I have converted a `Java` file to `Kotlin`, I get the error:

```
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

But, It only happens with 'make Project'. If I run 'debug app', It works fine (no problem).

- In fact I use:

1) `Multidex` Setting's for Google Guide

2) I checked it on Android Studio 3.2 and 3.0x

3) If I do not convert `Java` to `Kotlin`, It works, no problems.

Comment: What is your minSdk?

Comment: Possibly duplicate question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DexIndexOverflowException issue after updating to latest appcompat and support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515378/dexindexoverflowexception-issue-after-updating-to-latest-appcompat-and-support-l)

Comment: @Ge3ng min sdk is 17 (I do not use 21 Lollipop)

Comment: @AslamHossin 
I use multidex. and I had changed multidex library version. But did not work.

Comment: @SimplyGed No, It didn't work for me