# Android multidex support library using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Using Eclipse, is possible to generate an Android project using multidex for creating multiple
dex files? Searching over the net I found how to do that using gradle but nothing about to use that on
Eclipse without gradle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like ADT's [ant-tasks project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/legacy/ant-tasks/) is no longer maintained (it resides under 'legacy' folder).
So if you can't migrate to Gradle, you can edit the [DexExecTask](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/legacy/ant-tasks/src/main/java/com/android/ant/DexExecTask.java) manually. You'll have of course to rebuild the project locally..

**[Edit - 10/25/2014]** maven-android-plugin [does support multi-dex](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog). <s>However, it currently has a small issue: secondary dex files placed in wrong location. This [pull request](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/482) strives to fix that, so stay tuned!</s> (Fixed in 4.0.0)

Comment: Using android maven plugin for eclipse I've achieved generate multiple dex files. Now the problem is that the secondary dex files are saved inside the res/ folder inside the apk. The new multidex support of android needs these files in another location. Now, I'm expecting a new revision of the plugin that allows configure the path where to generate the dexes.

Comment: I see.. This is not what I understood from your question (consider to edit it).. Of course, the correct location is the root folder (where the main dex is located). There's a pull request that, once merged, is going to change the folder where dexes placed: http://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/482

Comment: Yes, I'm expecting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've merged manually the pull request with the last version of the plugin and it works.

Comment: @AlexLipov How to edit [DexExecTask](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/legacy/ant-tasks/src/main/java/com/android/ant/DexExecTask.java), inorder to compile with multidex?

Comment: @Amarnath It is open source. You can download the code, edit it as you wish, compile and replace the ant-tasks.jar in your sdk directory.

Comment: @AlexLipov yes i can understand. But i have big confusion on what to edit in that DexExecTask to generate the jar. do you have any guidance to me?

Comment: @Plebios can you let me know the steps what you did to overcome the issue 65K using maven plugin?

Comment: Alex's answer will only help to experience expert android Developers, NOT for a normal android developer.