# android-support-multidex.jar not working in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-multidex

Recently I faced 65K method limitation issue in my android project. Then I started to implement multidex in that projects. When I try to add this support library in eclipse, the issue not resolved. Still it showing the 65K limitation. But when its working fine in Gradle+Android studio. How can i achieve this in eclipse? Because I don't want to switch to Android studio now.

Here is the steps I have followed,

1) Added the android-support-multidex.jar into build path,
2) overrided, the below method in Application class. Since I am subclassing custom Application class.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    MultiDex.install(this);
}
```

But I can't able to achieve this in eclipse. Any solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever find a better solution than the answer below? Is there something simpler, or are all going to be retiring Eclipse for Android Studio soon?

Comment: @portfoliobuilder Its best go with Android studio. I think eclipse will retire soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530654/android-multidex-support-library-using-eclipse). Answer from Alex Lipov:

> It looks like ADT's [ant-tasks project](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/legacy/ant-tasks/) is no longer maintained (it
>   resides under 'legacy' folder).   So if you can't migrate to Gradle,
>   you can edit the [DexExecTask](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/legacy/ant-tasks/src/main/java/com/android/ant/DexExecTask.java) manually. You'll have of course to
>   rebuild the project locally..
>
> **[Edit - 10/25/2014]** maven-android-plugin [does support multi-dex](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog). However, it currently has a small issue: secondary dex
>   files placed in wrong location. This [pull request](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin/pull/482) strives to fix
>   that, so stay tuned!