# android pre dex errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, compiler-errors, dex

I recently try to open up a project developed sometime ago into Android Studio and try to rebuild it and I get whole load Android Pre Dex errors which I am totally stuck how I get rid of them. Tried a lot of stuff such as changing Android API level, cleaning, change jdk version.. all doesn't work.

Any experts out there can enlighten me what is the likely cause of these errors.?

[android pre dex errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BCyd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Add multidex enabled in default config

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "Your package name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 5
    versionName '1.0.5'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Step 2 : Add this library in your dependencies

```
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Step 3 : Add this line in your MyApplication extends Application java class

```
 MultiDex.install(this);
```

Step 4: Don't forgot to call MyApplication class in your Application tag of manifest file. Like this

```
 android:name=".MyApplication"
```

After this 4 steps clean your project and run the application. Surely it will helps you!

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks alot! Will try and get back! However in step 3 and 4.. i do not seem to have a MyApplication class.. do i have to create?

Comment: Yes you have to create new java class that extends Application.

Comment: public class MyApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MultiDex.install(this);
      }
      }}

Comment: It seems that they cannot find the MultiDex class in MyApplication. Do I have to add something else? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Manage to find out from to make MultiDex class recognized in Android Studio by following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910824/android-multidex-install

Comment: But this answer does not works.. still the same set of 22 Android Pre Dex errors... :(

Comment: for me multiDexEnabled true was enough no need for other steps

Answer (score 0):

i already solved it
it happen because you didnt setting the default java in android studio 2.3.3 or android studio 3.0 beta 6

1. go to file > project structure > SDK location
2. change the JDK Location to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131

[image: jdk location]