# DexIndexOverflowException in android

Tags: android, android-multidex

I Have a android eclipse project,Building new copy of the project using ant,while run time, i am getting the following **error**

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
       [dx] com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
       [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

I tried `MultiDexApplication` class `attachBaseContext()` method in my main application class still am getting the above problem,am i doing anything wrong?

Your response will be appreciated...

Comment: Are the number of methods above 65536 by any chance? It's the upper limit.

Comment: @Davlumbaz: yes,It is using some dependence projects,it may have chance to more methods.

Comment: post your build.gradle file

Comment: @war_Hero: Sorry,in android eclipse project is not having build.gradle file. it is having AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: this is answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library

Comment: @Droid Mind: i was seen previously no use,there you can see this comment "What is the Eclipse Ant fix, not gradle? "

Comment: @NageswaraRao.CH Check my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26556209/1233652).