# Eclipse enable multidex

Tags: java, android, apache-poi, android-multidex

I have this error on my Android project:

> [2015-11-24 20:50:09 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>   [2015-11-24 20:50:09 - MyApp] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

I read that, I should enable multidex but I can't.

I have this problem when I added ***poi-3.13-20150929.jar*** and ***poi-ooxml-3.13-20150929.jar*** in libs folder of my project. I added this library becouse I must write an xlsx file.

So, I would like to add multidex to resolve problem, but I don't say the way.

Please help me! Thanks!

Comment: I think you should start moving to android studio. As you can see support for eclipse is ending. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html. You might be able to fix your problem in eclipse. But all the documentation I can find about enabling multidex is for android studio

Comment: I don't want to migrate to android studio

Answer (score -2):

As fast as possible move to android studio ... there will see how life is easy

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Any examples? Will it solve the OP's exact problem, or just make other things better?

Comment: I don't wat to migrate to android studio @Gagravarr

Comment: in Build.gradle:
  deafult conf :        multiDexEnabled true

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
in yourApp extneds Application:
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530654/android-multidex-support-library-using-eclipse