# AWS android studio Dex error ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 in spite of multiDexEnabled = true

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-studio

I'm trying to install aws on android studio with [**add library dependency**]
on [**project structure**->**app**->**dependencies**->**+**]

 now i choose:

**com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.8**

Then I'm trying to start my android application but this error appears:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Now I'm trying this solution:

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled = true
   }
}
```

(on this site:
[Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536))

But then this error appears:

same fail but this time this line appears too:

```
Deprecated dynamic property: "multiDexEnabled" on
```

`"ProductFlavorDsl_Decorated{name=main, minSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=14,` `mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=ApiVersionImpl{mApiLevel=20, mCodename='null'},` `renderscriptTargetApi=-1, renderscriptSupportMode=null, renderscriptNdkMode=null,` `versionCode=1, versionName=1.0, applicationId=com.example.matthias.booksearch,` `testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null,` `testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null}", value: "true".`

I think the problem is something with gradle, because of Build Failure...
My dependencies of gradle.build are:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.9.8'
}
```

If someone use the aws-framework and it works, please write me back how you get started with it.

Comment: What version of the Android-Gradle plugin are you running?

Comment: The version of my Android-Gradle plugin is gradle 0.12.2

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle file add **multiDexEnabled true** to defaultConfig and **compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'** to your dependencies.

```
defaultConfig {

    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

}
```

Also, make sure you are using the latest **stable** version of **Android Studio 1.0.1** from the Stable Channel.

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 0):

`multiDexEnabled` support was added in v0.14.0 of the Android Gradle plugin, according to the release notes:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

It's not supported in 0.12.2, which is what you're running.

Please update to using the latest version of the plugin. You may need to update Android Studio to the latest version as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my gradle to 1.0.0 now I can configure multiDexEnable=true, 

this solves the Dex error, but now I am trying to add 2 librarys:

```
aws-android-sdk-2.1.5-sdb.debug ,

aws-android-sdk-2.1.5-sdb and com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.9.9
```

(last One as maven dependencies)

and trying to run my Application with some simpleDB code, but now this error appears:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
`> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: 
com/amazonaws/services/simpledb/AmazonSimpleDB.class
```

Some Solutions?