# Build Tools 21.1.2 – UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build-tools

I'm suddenly running into this issue when building/running my project.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/aidanfollestad/Documents/android-sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/aidanfollestad/Android Projects/Impression/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/aidanfollestad/Android Projects/Impression/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

My Gradle file contains this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.14.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'versionPlugin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.afollestad.impression"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 19
        versionName "0.7.0"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.photoview:library:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.4.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.18.0-rc'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev152-1.19.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.1.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

versionPlugin{
    buildTypesMatcher = 'release'
    supportBuildNumber = false
    fileNameFormat = '$appPkg-v$versionName-$versionCode'
}
```

My material-dialogs library references only AppCompat-v7, the same version this Gradle file is referencing. I don't have any JARs in my libs folder that I'm referencing. I have no idea what libraries are interfering with each other (other than the possibility of Play Services and AppCompat?). Any ideas or solutions?

I noticed Ion references v4 of the support library (https://github.com/koush/ion/blob/master/ion/build.gradle#L17), maybe that could be interfering with AppCompat?

Comment: @scott-barta this is not a duplicate, that other answer does not solve the issue.

Comment: I reopened it, but it is indeed a duplicate -- you have too many methods for one dex file to contain. It's not a collision.

Comment: If you aren't using every portion of Google Play services, consider using the [split dependencies](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#split) which allow you to only depend on the parts of Google Play services you actually need.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to enable multidex build.gradle :

```
android {
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled = true
   }
}
```

Ref : [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: using `multiDexEnabled` come's with it's own limitations. Try to avoid it, if possible.

Comment: @Shubham can you elaborate more on the limitations?

Comment: @Jus12: Read all about it here. http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Answer (score 11):

You may hitted the 65k methods limit. Instead of using multiDex, try to use Google Play Services with more granularity. [Follow this guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html), you can use only parts that you want. Probably this will fix your problem.

Comment: This is excellent advice, there's no need to enable multiDex (which appears to have caused me other issues) when you can just add the specific parts of Google Play Services that are needed.

Answer (score 2):

This exception shows that your project have reached to maximum number of methods 65536. you just do the below work.It worked for me

Step 1:
      inside build.gradle

```
      defaultConfig {  
       multiDexEnabled = true 
      }
```

Step 2:

inside manifest application tag

```
  android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" 

   or
```

Step 3: if You use Class which extends Application then do:

```
 public class MyApplication extends Application { 
   @Override 
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { 
    super.attachBaseContext(base); 
    MultiDex.install(this); 
    } 
    }
```

Step 4:

inside build.gradle

```
  android{
    dexOptions { 
    incremental true 
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" 
    }
   }
```