# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION when adding play-services

Tags: android, google-play-services, build.gradle

I have a project where I need to use the Google play service libary. But when I add it to my dependencies i get the following error:

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>    com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Reigstad\Documents\secret-tyrion-android\Tyrion\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Reigstad\Documents\secret-tyrion-android\Tyrion\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:283)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)>

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.21.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'org.immutables:gson:1.1.3'
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler:0.2.15'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tyrion.tyrion"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories { mavenCentral()}
```

I have tried all the solutions that I could find, but none of them seems to work for me. My project works fine, its just when I add the libary it wont work.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Build Tools 21.1.2 – UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497553/build-tools-21-1-2-unexpected-top-level-exception)

Comment: I did try that solution before asking my question. Dident help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may hitted the 65k methods limit. To use Google Play Services with more granularity, follow [this guide](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/google-play-services-and-dex-method.html), you can use only parts that you want. Probably this will fix your problem

Comment: I thought Ive allready tryed just using the 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.87'. But after a rollback and just using that it worked!! Thank you so much for making me try that solution again!

Comment: Wow, wish I had found this days ago!  Resolved the same issue for me as well.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks :)