# i am getting this error always Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, dalvik, dex

When i am trying to compile my code i am getting this error always
"**Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536**", but i don't know what is this error actually i am not able to generate my APK.

In my project i have used around 4 library project.

1. Facebook SDK
2. Google play services
3. Chat Library
4. Amazon AWS S3 Bucket jar

So please kindly go through my post and suggest me some valuable suggestion.

Comment: *but i don't know what is this error actually* did you at least tried to use  google search with description of  this error?

Comment: You have hit the 16-bit dex methods limit.  See https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: did you tried to clean project?

Comment: hey thanks but i am using eclipse can you tell me how to do it ????

Comment: yes i have tried Clean project, new workspace everything but still it's not able to compile...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Comment: Chris is right indeed

Comment: If you search StackOverflow for "Unable to execute dex method id", there are tons of hits for exactly this problem. Before asking a new question, you should see if there are any existing questions that match your problem.

Comment: This issue is very known and very embarassing: The problem is that you imported lot of methods inside in your app through the different Libraries.  I recommand to read this article :[https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71 ]  A method to bypass this limit.

Comment: hey can you tell me the solution how to solve this issue, do i need to add android-support-multidex.jar into my libs folder...

Answer (score 0):

In Android Per Application only 65536 references are allowed.

Your are using so many Sdks which increases method references.

In Android Studio You can use individual library from google play service such as

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

with these lines:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

complete list is available here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Some APIs do not have a separate library; include them by including the base library