# Error import Eclipse project into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, import

When I import a Eclipse project to Android Studio I see this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Bernardo\android-sdks\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Bernardo\AndroidstudioProjects\RcForcaVendas\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Users\Bernardo\AndroidstudioProjects\RcForcaVendas\app\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Answer (score 0):

> com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0,
>   0xffff]: 65536

When your **application** and the **libraries** it references reach a certain size, you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture.

For more info see [Building Apps with Over 65K Methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

You may use following ways to overcome this issue as

1. Get rid of any third-party libraries that you don't really need.
2. Use a [multidex setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) for your application.