# libGDX + com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0 : android:dexDebug

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx, google-play-services

I made a game with libgdx.

When I add the next line to gradle:

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0"
```

It does sync correctly. But then I try to run my app and the next error emerges:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\[...]\Android\sdk2\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\[...]\android\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\[...]\android\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
    2
Output:
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

Google Play Services and Android Support Library are installed and updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to selectively add only the part of the Google Play Services that you actually need. See this for reference.

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup

```
Google Play services API    Description in build.gradle

Google+ com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.0.0
Google Account Login    com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.0.0
Google Actions, Base Client Library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.0.0
Google App Indexing com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:7.0.0
Google Analytics    com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.0.0
Google Cast com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:7.0.0
Google Cloud Messaging  com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.0.0
Google Drive    com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.0.0
Google Fit  com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:7.0.0
Google Location, Activity Recognition, and Places   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0
Google Maps com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.0.0
Google Mobile Ads   com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.0.0
Google Nearby   com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:7.0.0
Google Panorama Viewer  com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:7.0.0
Google Play Game services   com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:7.0.0
SafetyNet   com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:7.0.0
Google Wallet   com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.0.0
Android Wear    com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

`LibGDX` is a fairly large library, have you either enabled `multidex` or tried to remove unused code?

To do so simply in build.gradle

```
`android {
   defaultConfig {
      ...
      multiDexEnabled = true
   }
}`
```

Try taking a look at this thread and see if any of these are of any aid to you if this was not the issue:

[Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: LibGDX isn't the problem, adding the **entire google play services** is