# Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' when build project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio for the first time and I got the following error after importing the project (previously it was an eclipse project where I had issues too.)

Here is the information given:

```
   Error:Execution failed for task ':xink:dexDebug'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output E:\xink App\Xink\xink\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=E:\xink App\Xink\xink\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:
>       UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>       com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

The app build.gradle is this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.vog.xink"
            minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 21
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile project(':swipecard')

    compile files('libs/android-query-full.0.26.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')


    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')

    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-betar.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')


    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:+'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15209831

Comment: Did you try _`Build->Clean Project` and/or `File->Invalidate Cache/Restart` then rebuild the whole project?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably including the same library more than once. Try to include just one `google-api-client` and just one `google-http-client`.