# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION : DexIndexOverflowException while running the app on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using google play services version 7.5.0 and getting below mentioned error while running a project.

My project contains 2 modules.
Here are the build.gradle file of each modules.

**Module 1:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

**Module 2:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':module1')
}
```

**And here is build.gradle file of app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vserv.offerwall"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':module2')
}
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

When I am building the app, it get build successfully. But when I am trying to run the app, I am getting below mentioned error.

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
>       at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>       at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>       at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>    com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

I have done some Google and found below mentioned link.

[Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

I have tried this and edited the app gradle file by adding  `multiDexEnabled true` into defaultConfig and `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'` in dependencies.

After that the above mentioned error is resolved and then I got another error while running the app.

> :app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents FAILED
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't read [D:\StudioWorkspace\SampleSDKDemoProject\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\allclasses.jar] (Can't process class [org/fmod/FMODAudioDevice.class] (256))

Kindly help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing ALL modules from google services

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

Import only the modules you need. Check [this page](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

> Note: If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K
>   limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this
>   problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google
>   Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them.

Comment: It helped me, but even if my methods count will exceed 65k then what should be the appropriate action to resolve