# Facebook integration with Libgdx Gradle android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to libgdx on android studio. I am trying to integrate facebook with the android project. I am following this link([Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#androidstudio)) to integrate it with the android module.
When I press sync I am supposed to be able to import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;

But it doesnt work that way.No matter what I try I get error cannot resolve symbol 'facebook'

In build.gradle of android module I have added:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.4.jar')
    compile files(some adnetwork jars)
}
```

I also tried to add the compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0' in main build.gradle under project(":android") doesn't work either.

I tried syncing gradle several times, restarting android studio also File-> invalidatecaches/restart nothing seems to help.

Am I missing some step. Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself. I used cmd to build the project and what I found is that it failed because of "Unable to execute dex" problem (Too many methods) [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536).

For people with similar problem in the future run this in your root project folder using cmd: `gradlew build --stacktrace`
`
This will clearly give the reasons why the build had failed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are adding it in the wrong place.
In the root of you Libgdx Project open the build.gradle

add your line:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
```

inside the *dependencies* in *`project(":android")`*

Rerun your build.gradle so it synchronizes and you should see:

```
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.1.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.1.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.pom
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/parse/bolts/bolts-android/1.2.0/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar
Download https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/4.1.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.1.0.aar
```