# Error when building debug

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to debug my app in Android Studio I get a gradle error. I have now idea how I can fix it. Does anyone have any ideas or fixes for me so I can continue debugging my app. I googled it already and people are saying the cause could be that there are duplicate imports in the gradle file but I checked this and there are none. When I rebuilt gradle it is successful but when I debug I get this error.

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBalysvMaterialmenuMaterialMenu154Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJohnkilAndroidRobototextviewRobototextview240Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /Users/x/Development/Android SDK/build-tools/21.1.2/dx --dex --no-optimize --output /Users/app/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug --input-list=/Users/app/app/build/intermediates/tmp/dex/debug/inputList.txt
  Error Code:
    2
  Output:

    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 42.045 secs
```

My build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

def AAVersion = '3.3.2'
def JacksonVersion = '2.5.2'

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
//        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
        // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

        // you should set your package name here if you are using different application IDs
         resourcePackageName "com.app"

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.handlers'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.schemas'
        exclude 'META-INF/spring.tooling'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

    compile(
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: "$JacksonVersion"],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: "$JacksonVersion"],
            [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: "$JacksonVersion"]
    )

    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"

    compile "org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M2"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0"

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'

    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.4.0'

    compile 'com.balysv.materialmenu:material-menu:1.5.4'

    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you reached dex methods count limit, one dex file can contain max 65536. You can try to **remove redundant libraries and reduce methods** count or implement [multidex](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) application and add as many methods as you want.

[Here](http://frogermcs.github.io/MultiDex-solution-for-64k-limit-in-Dalvik/)'s a great example of multidex implementation with possible workarounds and tricks.

Comment: I tried this but I got an OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exeeded

Comment: Please follow instructions step-by-step. If you get OOM, it means that you didn't set     `dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }`

Answer (score 1):

### Whats your Logcat Throws

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
```

some of your jar files does not compile. You should go into your build.gradle file in your project, and look in your dependencies.

Just enable `multiDexEnabled true`

```
defaultConfig {

    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

See [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)
and
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: When I add this I get an OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exeeded

Comment: @BartBergmans yes yes .https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded

Comment: restart the android studio