# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, android-studio, andengine, android-multidex

I have below dependencies in my Gradle file :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "packagename"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            jni.srcDirs = []
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile files('libs/FLurry_3.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/pixel-perfect-collision.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar')
    compile project(':zip_file')
    compile project(':andEngine')
    compile project(':andEnginePhysicsBox2DExtension')
    compile project(':downloader_library')
    compile project(':viewPagerLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

On building gradle file I am getting below error of :

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

To solve this error I have already added multidex dependency :

```
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Still looping around ..

Edited : Already solved problem so do not try to duplicate it and solution is below..!!

Hoping for help.!

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add

```
  multiDexEnabled true
```

in `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {

    applicationId 'pkg'
    minSdkVersion 
    targetSdkVersion 
    versionCode 
    versionName 

    // Enable MultiDexing:  https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: If you have multiple modules, you will have to add this to every module's android block.

Answer (score 3):

It means your app exceeds 65k method count limit of android app.
It seems you are using google play service which is mammoth.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

As [this document](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) says

You can reduce this by using only the play services you need shown in the same link above.
Example if your app only needs gcm you can use its subset like:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

this problem occurs while your whole project have more then `64000` methods.
so you have to add dependency to application `build.gradle` file

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

and then add this tag to `AndrodManifest.xml` to application item

```
 <application
    ...
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
```

If your app uses extends the Application class add this code

```
@Override
public void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    MultiDex.install(base);
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
}
```

and then next step is to  Add multidex support to defaultConfig at `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    ...
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

...
see http://phpidiots.in/android/unexpected-top-level-exception/