# Android studio- Execution failed for task :app:dexDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.clickaley.eric.restaurants"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://jzaccone.github.io/SlidingMenu-aar" }
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu:library:1.3@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
}
```

Can't figure out where is the problem.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process `'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java''` finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: here `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` you are including all the jars in the libs folder and here `compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')` you are adding one by name. why ?

Comment: Can you please delete the bin folder app module and clean the project and see?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain tried to remove the lines but still getting that error.

Comment: @NitinMesta can't seem to find the folder

Comment: You need to be in Project level to find the folder structure .Switch from Drop down from android to project . And go to your app folder where you can find build folder. Delete it and clean the project.

Comment: @NitinMesta Found the problem was com.google.android.gms:play-services too large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here was the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107287/1868773)

Remove:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' And replacing it with:

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0' compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
```