# Android Unable to execute dex error after cloning correct project

Tags: android, git, navigationview, android-multidex

This is a really strange problem and I've been days stuck with it: we've got a working project (no errors whatsoever) in a git repository. Everything is OK (it's even published in Google Play) when executing the project from the creator's equip, but, when we try to clone it in a different equip (we've tried Mac, Linux and Windows), this exception is thrown:

```
 Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Hereafter, even if we apply the multidex solution as described in Android Developers or delete the unused dependencies, the app raises an exception when trying to load class `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView` (coming from a NoClassDefFound in runtime).

I suspect maybe it has something to do with the gradle plugin or appcompat libs version, but so far, nothing we've tried has worked.

**Edit:** This is not a common multiDex error, I'm pretty familiarized about how to solve them, it's about one computer executing the app without problems but when you clone the same project from git in other computer, it won't run and the MultiDex error is thrown.

**EDIT 2**: mi dependenvy list is as follows (I ommit the company libs but they're not the problem

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.mo2o.third:valnif:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.0.0'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.6.0'
compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Comment: can you post your build.gradle dependencies too

Comment: What does "equip" mean? As in "creator's equip" and "a different equip"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: Googling the error message gave me that question and answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am agree with you its a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Comment: In the future, be sure to post the complete stacktrace when you encounter an exception.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, you've found the solution to the method ID not in [...], my problem is another one (see the edited question).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, I'm spaniard, sorry, so by "my equip" or "creator's equip" I mean computers.

Comment: please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536