# Application Failed To Run Due To Gradle

Tags: android, gradle

Iam developing an android application where i need to user JACKSON parse so i included it in my gradle and it builds successfully but fails to run

My Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'Mustafa'
        keyPassword '123456'
        storeFile file('E:/RakbnyCer.jks')
        storePassword '123456'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.musta.rakbny"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1'
}
```

Error

Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareCnPedantSweetalertLibrary13Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk4101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable840Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMcxiaokeVolleyLibraryAar100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPnikosisMaterialishProgress10Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:484)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:261)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:473)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:161)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"simple","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","sources":[{}]}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.17 secs
```

Comment: Please post the entire Gradle console output, not just those couple of lines.

Comment: Added the whole gradle output

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Comment: i added in my gradle dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
} then i get the same error

Comment: Do you need *all* the play services? Please see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Comment: I also see you have Volley and the Apache HTTP library... You probably should just use one of those. Also Jackson isn't necessary if you have Gson...

Comment: "i added in my gradle dexOptions { javaMaxHeapSize "4g" } then i get the same error" -- that is not a complete solution to the problem. The answers on that question -- particularly [the one that has been upvoted 200+ times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26196397/115145), cover how to address this by using multidex. That being said, cricket_007's points are very good, and you can perhaps avoid all the multidex hassle just by reducing your dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to enable MultiDex as you crossed the limit of 64k methods in your app by adding another library