# Android build error DexIndexOverflowException

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, dex

I am not able to build my Android app.  I keep seeing this error:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:484)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:261)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:473)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:161)
>           at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
>           at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
>           at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

However, it doesn't tell me which gradle dependencies are causing my build to fail.  How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Igor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to execute dex: method ID not in \[0, 0xffff\]: 65536](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: @Paul Is that still the best solution in 2016?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable multidexing with the new Android Multidex support library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609734/how-to-enable-multidexing-with-the-new-android-multidex-support-library)

Comment: @mbmc How is that a duplicate?

Comment: You reached the limit: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html, gotta enable multidex.

Comment: If you don't want to enable multidex, then read the link I've posted to avoid reaching the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the only way to solve my dilemma was to enable multidex in my project:

1. In AndroidManifest.xml:

`<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

2. In app's build.gradle:

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'`

and

```
defaultConfig {
     testInstrumentationRunner "com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner"
     multiDexEnabled true
```