# Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff] while using jxl library

Tags: android, jxl, android-multidex

I am working with export my database file in excel sheet. For this I am using jxl.jar in android eclipse. Only After I add this lib error occurs.What is solution for this?

Comment: see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Comment: I just solved my problem using add jxl.jar as a external jar instead of put in lib folder

Comment: But now i m getting Error : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl.WorkbookSettings