# com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessExaception: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

i getting this exception whenever i tried to run the project as method count overflow but when i build signed apk it runs fine ..furthermore i enabled proguard for realse so it is proguard which prevents multidex.. i get confused about multidex whether it is good or bad & why it is not showing any error while genrating signed apk .. any help is appriciated..below is my build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        //multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }

    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile(project(':facebook')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
    compile project(':Volley')
    compile project(':squarecamera')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.4.0'


    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.2'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-toaster:0.0.10'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.malinskiy:superrecyclerview:1.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'
    compile 'com.github.lecho:hellocharts-library:1.5.5@aar'
    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compil'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.+@aar'
    compile 'com.klinkerapps:android-chips:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'

}
```

Comment: Hey use only one time com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0

Comment: @Harin thank u so much for your response  i removed it but still it is coming as com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536..

Comment: ok now set multiDexEnabled  true and add com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0 dependency in gradle. and for more information go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Comment: but why it required to enable multidex as for realse version of apk it is not showing any error..

Comment: Because `buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled true`...

Comment: So due to minifyenabled true ..it prevent multidex @cricket_007?

Comment: No, your release version is likely not getting an error because you have minified the build. I don't think it has anything to do with multidex or disables multidex

Comment: Can u please give actual meaning of mified enabled..