# Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 Error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to integrate [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) in my android application to read data from my firebase database. I am using Eclipse for Android application development. After adding `firebase-client-android-2.5.2.jar` library I cannot run my application. I am getting an error like

```
[2016-08-19 02:17:23 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
[2016-08-19 02:17:23 - MyApplication] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Also I am getting a warning like,

```
[2016-08-19 02:17:13 - MyApplication] Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$2) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2016-08-19 02:17:19 - MyApplication] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.shaded.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You have reached the 64K DEX method reference limit. The best way to manage it is to migrate to Android Studio and use the multidex. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Comment: Is there is any way to solve this issue in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Check the build **path** -> **Java Build Path** -> **Order and Export tab** -> **uncheck Android private Librairies**.

Comment: try the following line :  dex.force.jumbo=true to the project.properties file

Comment: i highly advise you to use  Android Studio and enable Multidex.

Comment: Can we enable Multidex in Eclipse?. How we can enable it?,  Can we use "android-support-multidex" for that?

Comment: unfortunately  it is deprecated because Eclipse is no longer supported by Google