# Android Dex error while building APK

Tags: android, gradle, apk, dex

I'm getting the below error while attempting to build APK. I have read several posts on how to resolve the problem, but as I have not been developing for that long, i'm unsure what I am doing. So, hope someone can help.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: 
        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

This is my build.gradle (Module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.dawnlp.mymap"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

and this is my build.gradle project

```
/ Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Would appreciate it if someone could help out, also bare in mind I'm a little inexperienced.

Comment: you have to enable multidex as your methods are more than 65536  or you can simple replace play-services library with what ever is needed like ad etc

Comment: Enable [multidex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it :

```
android{
    defaultConfig {

            multiDexEnabled true
        }
}
```

And use it too

```
   dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean place 
defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true
}

into 
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}

Comment: Like this

dependencies {

defaultConfig {

    multiDexEnabled true
}

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable multidex, add this line to your defaultConfig :

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

And this line to your dependencies :

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Also, as you are running unit tests, you need to create a class that extends the application and install MultiDex :

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Where is defaultConfig?

Comment: In the build.gradle (Module) file.

Answer (score 0):

use this block in your module level gradle :
 **dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }**

And in manifest change the application name to **.multidex**.
hope your code will work fine now