# ERROR building apk android studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. >

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I can't create the apk of my application.

Android Studio give me this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

I don't know what to do. Can someone help me please?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536

Comment: formatting, capitalisation and punctuation