# com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Tags: android, android-studio, android-multidex

I already enable multidex in my project but still received this error after my project building, need some help, guys.
Android Studio 3.5.2, Gradle build tools 3.0.1.

support_multidex               : "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
}

public class MyApplication extends Application {

     @Override
        protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
            super.attachBaseContext(base);
            MultiDex.install(this);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my app, this error was solved by this first option.

In my `build.gradle` file, under `android` I just added this code.

```
dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Another option they recommend is this one.

```
dexOptions {
          jumboMode true
}
```

I guess you will have more understanding on this problem by this two links.

[Interesting stackoverflow conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209831/unable-to-execute-dex-method-id-not-in-0-0xffff-65536)

[Google Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex)