# How to check if Android app is nearing 65k method limit

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, dex

Having a very large android app how can i check if my app is approaching the [65k limit](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) ?Is there any tool for this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get count of number methods used in a jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023397/is-there-a-way-to-get-count-of-number-methods-used-in-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this tool](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts), It works amazingly well.

Also you can read [this](https://medium.com/@rotxed/dex-skys-the-limit-no-65k-methods-is-28e6cb40cf71) article to help you understand a lot more about this topic.