# Count number of method in a Library (Jar/AAR)

Tags: android, methods, count, dex

How do we count the number of methods in a Library file.

For eg, a Jar or AAR.

This is required to know the number of android resource IDs used by the library used by the project. This would help in estimating how close we are to 65K dex limit in Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get count of number methods used in a jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023397/is-there-a-way-to-get-count-of-number-methods-used-in-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 10):

- [dexcount-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin): gradle plugin, works for any Android project (***library*** or ***application***), nice D3 sunburst partition chart output.
- [dex-method-counts](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts): command-line tool, supports ***apk*** / ***zip*** / ***dex*** / ***directory***.
- <s>[Methods Count](http://www.methodscount.com/): only works for ***online public library***, just give library 'compile' statement (e.g., com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4).</s>
- [APK method count](http://inloop.github.io/apk-method-count/): only works for ***APK***, expandable tree results.

Comment: True - https://medium.com/@rotxed/sunsetting-methodscount-com-cb5693a9586  thanks @mahe madhi

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you give this site a try, [MethodsCount](http://www.methodscount.com/). It also gives you with an awesome Android Studio plugin which add method count beside all your libraries in the build.gradle file.

You can also try [this](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin) and [this](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts). I have tried both of them and they are worth checking.

Comment: Mihail Parparita's [dex-method-counts](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts)  is one of the best available.

Comment: Unfortunately the very nice MethodsCount website is being discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a small [shell script](https://github.com/hydro0/aar-methods-count) that uses a solution, provided on other  [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14026180/4069913) for jar files. Maybe still could be useful. It takes AAR file and returns methods count. But you have to have Android SDK installed for that.